# Is it okay to use both fetchpriority="high" and loading="eager" in img tag?

Tags: html, css, frontend

### Is it okay to use both fetchpriority="high" and loading="eager" in img tag ?

- fetchpriority attribute not supported in firefox browser.
- If i used both, how the assets prefetching works... should it cause performance issues

Comment: Are your users majority Firefox users? Then no. Have you tested and benchmarked both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**

Fetchpriority and loading serve different purposes and can still be used together in an `img` tag.

They may have similarity by definition in loading resources but they differ in terms of handling the resources.

1. Fetchpriority - It is used to indicate that the resource should be fetched as soon as possible. It is handy when you want to guarantee that some resources load faster than others by prioritizing vital content for a better user experience.

Whereas,

2. Loading - used to indicate that the resource should be immediately, without delaying the rendering of the rest of the page.

Overall, `fetchpriority` is concerned with the priority of fetching resources
and `loading` is focused on the loading behavior of the resource.

By setting `loading` to `eager`, it will instruct the browser to immediately start fetching the resource.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**

`loading="eager"` is the default loading behaviour of the browser -> [web.dev - The loading attribute](https://web.dev/articles/browser-level-image-lazy-loading#the_loading_attribute). So applying this to an image won't do anything.

> The eager value is simply an instruction to load the image as usual, without delaying the load further if it is off-screen. It does not imply that the image is loaded any quicker than another image without the loading="eager" attribute.

`fetchpriority="high"` will make sure the image is downloaded sooner than it would normally be -> [web.dev - Fetch Priority](https://web.dev/articles/fetch-priority). So if you use this on your LCP (Largest Contentful Paint) you will improve the performance of the page.